# How to use multiple List<> as DatagridView's datasource

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, datasource

I'm looking for a highly efficient way to save data to a table like structure in C#. The number of rows, columns and data type for each column is determined at runtime. One of my approaches is to create a struct that defines a column. The struct consists of ColumnName, Units, and a generic List of doubles. (For now I am sticking to one data type). I then instantiate a struct for each column and fill its list. This method works pretty well and is much cleaner than some other methods we've tried, I am able to save 100,000 rows of 3 columns in about 12 milliseconds.
The problem I am having is displaying the data. I am able to display my "table" in a datagridview by looping through my columns and rows and filling the DGV cell by cell, but this is, not suprisingly, very slow.
Is there a way to use my 3 lists as a datasource for the DGV? Can each column have it's own datasource? Is the an alternative to the DataGridView that I should try?

Comment: (re your comment, I added an example for `ITypedList` so you can get a feel for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the "3 lists" here? I can see the list of doubles... if the columes are dynamic, then implementing `ITypedList` might be useful, but I'll be honest - it is a pig to implement correctly; it would be easier to fill a `DataTable`. I've used this, for example, to transpose an array on the fly.

If performance is your concern, perhaps switch to [virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx)? This would appear to match your use-case quite well.

Comment: Each of the 3 lists represents a column. My test app contains a textbox for the user to enter the number of rows and columns and I've been using 3 X 100,000 typically. Real world could be more like 8 x 1,000,000.
My first attempt was to simply write data directly to a DataTable but performance was not great with large # of rows.
Copying my the contents of my lists to a DataTable and using that as the DGV datasource is quicker than going cell by cell, but could present some other challanges.
I'll have to investigate ITypedList and VirtualMode.

Comment: My first choice would be virtual mode. I have some `ITypedList` examples kicking around on usenet if you want.

Comment: For example, http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/browse_thread/thread/ae1251a6855b9254/f5599f934a2f7043

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried filling a DataTable first and then binding that DataTable to the DataGridView?

If it's a WebApplication you can do a foreach statement and build a table from code-behind.

Comment: See comment above re: DataTable